# No me deja instalar mi apk en versiones inferiores a android 7

Tags: android, gradle, apk

Durante todo el proyecto, se ha podido instalar la app desde Android studio en diferentes versiones de Android y nunca ha habido ningún problema. Cuando he generado hoy la apk, al instalarlo en teléfonos cuya versión de Android supera la 7 no hay ningún problema, pero si la versión es inferior no deja instalar.
**Me he asegurado que permita aplicaciones eternas y el instant run está desactivado**

**build.gradle Module:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.drinkme.sdm.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-rc1'
    compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-rc1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-rc1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-rc1'
}
```

**build.gradle Project:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/mediano_sin_fondo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/mediano_sin_fondo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".crearCuenta.CrearCuentaActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PerfilActivity"
            android:label="Perfil"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MasLogrosActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Si necesitais más información pedidla.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: puedes ponder tu manifest porfavor

Comment: Sergio, bienvenido a Stackoverflow... ¿Aplicaciones eternas o externas? ¿Da algún mensaje de error en alguna parte?

Comment: @tebitoq ya lo tienes

Comment: @A.Cedano no me ha saltado ninún mensaje de error. Simplemente intenta instalar y en lugar de instalarla te dice: Aplicacion no instalada

Comment: Sergio ¿revisaste en la configuración de ese dispositivo en específico **si no tiene algún tipo de bloqueo con respecto a la instalación de aplicaciones**, en el menú desarrollador o en otra parte? Estás depurando por conexión USB me imagino. Hay una opción llamada más o menos `Instalar vía USB` y otra llamada más o menos: `Depuración USB`...

Comment: @A.Cedano se ha probado en varios dispositivos, no solo en uno. En el caso del mío tengo activada la parte de depuración USB, pero no la de instalación

Comment: Sergio, prueba a poner esto en el `Manifest`, antes de la etiqueta `application`: , arriba:  **`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
     android:debuggable="false"`**

Comment: @A.Cedano sigue fallando

Comment: Es muy extraño. ¿La App compila bien, sin errores? A mi me parece que debe ser algún tipo de permiso en las opciones del desarrollador.

Comment: @SergioSantano " se ha probado en varios dispositivos, no solo en uno." Pero has probado en varios dispositivos con android menor a 7.0??

Comment: revisa el atributo minSdkVersion que es donde indicas la versión de Android mínima en la que va a poder ser instalado, además revisa los otros atributos de esa zona que son los que te pueden generar esos problemas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pueden ser dos cosas. La primera observa que tienes un minSdk de 21, puede que estés intentando instalar en versiones inferiores a esa versión y por ese te genere ese error. Y segundo, si el apk que estas generando es firmado, debes habilitar una opción para versiones inferiores para que el apk generado no te de errores en ciertos dispositivos.